# how to get distance using $within $centerSphere

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geospatial

i'm using `$within` `$centerSphere` to get only the documents of collection that are inside the circle with a certain radius.

The query that i use is:

```
{"value.pos":{"$within":{"$centerSphere":
[[40.6861735,14.777354800000012],0.0007839325190887568]}}}
```

where `0.0007839325190887568` = `5 * 6378.1` ( earth radius ).

What i need is to show the distance between the point and the position of the element of the document.

I'm using mongodb driver for nodejs.

After receiving the distance i need to order the results programmatically only and just only the user want it.

I can't use mongoose because i need to change too much my existing code so i want to use standard mongodb driver.

Is there a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$within has been deprecated since 2.4. To do what you want, make sure you are running at least MongoDB 2.4 and use [geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear) in an aggregation pipeline stage. Using aggregation is necessary to get the distance in the results.

```
db.places.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
            distanceField: "distance",
            maxDistance: < your distance in meters>,
            spherical: true
        }
    }
])
```

Make sure you have a 2dsphere index on `value.pos`.